# !strcmp as substitute for ==

Tags: c++, strcmp, rapidxml

I'm working with rapidxml, so I would like to have comparisons like this in the code:

```
if ( searchNode->first_attribute("name")->value() == "foo" )
```

This gives the following warning:

```
comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]
```

Is it a good idea to substitute it with:

```
if ( !strcmp(searchNode->first_attribute("name")->value() , "foo") )
```

Which gives no warning?

The latter looks ugly to me, but is there anything else?

Comment: *It's not just a good idea, it's the law.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot in general use `==` to compare strings in C, since that only compares the address of the first character which is not what you want.

You must use `strcmp()`, but I would endorse this style:

```
if( strcmp(searchNode->first_attribute("name")->value(), "foo") == 0) {  }
```

rather than using `!`, since that operator is a boolean operator and `strcmp()`'s return value is not boolean. I realize *it works* and is well-defined, I just consider it ugly and confused.

Of course you can wrap it:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

static bool first_attrib_name_is(const Node *node, const char *string)
{
    return strcmp(node->first_attribute("name")->value(), string) == 0;
}
```

then your code becomes the slightly more palatable:

```
if( first_attrib_name_is(searchNode, "foo") ) {  }
```

Note: I use the `bool` return type, which is standard from C99.

Comment: I would agree that `!strcmp` is counterintuitive, but it got so widely used over the years that it became idiomatic to C language.

Comment: Shouldn't first_attrib_name_is return a bool tho'?

Comment: @MatsPetersson It most certainly should, old habits die very hard some times. Thanks, I edited.

Comment: Thank you, I might just add the function in our StringUtil class.

Answer (score 2):

If the `value()` returns `char*` or `const char*`, you have little choice - `strcmp` or one of its length-limiting alternatives is what you need. If `value()` can be changed to return `std::string`, you could go back to using `==`.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing char* types with "==" you just compare the pointers. Use the C++ string type if you want to do the comparison with "=="

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

You can use `strcmp`, but I would recommend wrapping it. e.g.

```
bool equals(const char* a, const char* b) {
    return strcmp(a, b) == 0;
}
```

then you could write: `if (equals(searchNode->first_attribute("name")->value(), "foo"))`

---

You can convert the return value to a `std::string` and use the `==` operator

```
if (std::string(searchNode->first_attribute("name")->value()) == "foo")
```

That will introduce a string copy operation which, depending on context, may be undesirable.

---

You can use a string reference class. The purpose of a string reference class is to provide a string-like object which does not own the actual string contents. I've seen a few of these and it's simple enough to write your own, but since Boost has a string reference class, I'll use that for an example.

```
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>
using namespace boost;

if (string_ref(searchNode->first_attribute("name")->value()) == string_ref("foo"))
```